# Roleprovider that supports hierarchical roles/permissions?

Tags: permissions, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I am building a web application that will have hierarchical roles.

For example, an admin, mod, user roles.

If a user was a moderator, and a .IsInRole("User") was done, then it would return true because mod is on top of user. There will also be a permissions table to have allow(true)/deny(false) for a variety of actions for the different roles.

There would also be different 'starting' roles that would branch down; admin2, mod2, user2, but a regular mod would not be considered a user2, only a regular user.

Are there any libraries that allow this type of role/permissions functions?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly look at using a claims based scheme instrad of roles.  However, my firat reaction would be to create a custom IPrincipal object, override the IsInRole method, and use bitwise flag enum for your roles (you know, 1, 2, 4, 8) values.

My open source project has a working implementation of claims based.
https://github.com/wcpro/scaffr-generated